# Remote validation isn't working in mvc.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes

I am using remote validator but it's not working even debugger isn't tracing that method.

```
     public JsonResult CheckStrategyName(string StrategyName)
        {
            var ab = from a in db.Sterategy where a.StrategyName == StrategyName select a.StrategyName;

            return !ab.Any() ? Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) : Json(string.Format("Name Already esists"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I have used it here

```
        [Required]
        [Remote("CheckStrategyName", "St", ErrorMessage = "Already exists ")]     
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string StrategyName { get; set; }
```

Webconfig

```
    <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
```

Where am I making mistake ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server code & settings seems to be fine. Make sure the following are in place

1. You are using the TextBoxFor helper method to generate the relevant input field markup and **it is inside a form**.

   ```
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {       
      @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.StrategyName)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.StrategyName)    

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   }
   ```
2. You have included the javascript libraries needed for validation.

   ```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
   ```

Comment: I didn't include those libraries. Now it's working, thanks a lot.